# I'm getting this errorwhen I'm starting the server ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Showing C:/Users/Jacob Zabner/Desktop/My ror/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out: I needed to change the first parameter in lines 7 and 8 of the file `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` from `application` to `default`.